# Reusing values in condition and consequent for efficiency in lisp / clojure

Tags: performance, clojure, lisp, conditional-statements

I have a cond, e.g of the form:

```
(cond
  (condition1) (consequent1)
  (condition2) (consequent2))
```

Say in condition2 I want to compute some value which is expensive, so I would prefer to only do it once.  If condition2 is true then I would like to use this expensive value in consequent2.  My dilemma is then that I don't want to recompute the value in the condition and consequent, since this is wasteful.  I also don't want to throw the whole cond inside a larger let function, e.g.

```
(let [value-used-in-cond2 do-expensive-computation]
  (cond
  (condition1) (consequent1)
  (condition2) (consequent2)))
```

since I don't want to compute this value if I never get to condition 2, i.e. if condition1 is true.

Is there an idiomatic way to deal with this? The first thing that comes to mind is to memoizing the expensive function, but there must be simpler solution.

Comment: Take a look at `condp` and its use of `:>>`.

Comment: This can also be modeled using lazy evaluation semantics

Answer (score 8):

In *On Lisp*, Paul Graham describes macros for anaphoric variants of Common Lisp conditionals which bind the symbol 'it to the value of the condition expression. These macros obey the same evaluation semantics as the normal conditional forms, so from your example, `condition2` will be evaluated after `condition1` and only if `condition1` is false. All conditions will be evaluated at most once. You can download *On Lisp* at http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisptext.html, and the code for the anaphoric macros is in figure 14.1 on page 191.

Comment: And to bit a bit more direct, check out Graham's acond macro.

Answer (score 4):

A somewhat ugly solution that should work in Clojure is

```
(let [expensive-result (or (condition1) (do-expensive-computation)] 
   (cond (condition1) (consequent1)
         (condition2) (consequent2)))
```

This however requires condition1 to be evaluated twice.

Assuming that lisp / clojure in the heading means Clojure *or (another) lisp*,
in Common Lisp you can do

```
(let (var)
   (cond
      ((condition1) (consequent1))
      ((setq var (condition2)) (consequent2))))
```

but this will not work in Clojure at the local variable is immutable.

You can use an atom to accomplish something similar with Clojure.

```
(let [v (atom nil)]
  (cond
    (condition1) (consequent1)
    (do (reset! v (expensive)) (condition2 @v)) (consequent2 @v)))
```

Comment: You can do the same thing with atoms in Clojure.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `delay` to compute something at most once and use it zero or more times:

```
(let [expensive-thing (delay do-expensive-computation)]
  (cond (condition1) (consequent1)
        (condition2 @expensive-thing) (consequent2 @expensive-thing)))
```

Answer (score 2):

One way of rewriting this in Clojure to avoid repeating the computation would be:

```
(or
  (when (condition1) (consequent1))
  (when-let [val2 (condition2)] (consequent2 val2)))
```

This works assuming that `consequent1` and `consequent2` never return `nil` - otherwise evaluation of the `or` would fall through to the next form.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but I only have two case condition so I used a combination of a function and the if-let macro so:

```
(defn- expensive-computation
  [a b]
  (if (test (compute a b)) a nil))

(if-let [foo (expensive-computation a b)]
  (consequent2 foo)
  (consequent1))
```

As you can see the value is only computed once, after that a simple comparison is done to check if the test of the computation was sucessfull or not. If the test was not sucessful then it return nil, thus executing consequent1.
It is not a super clean solution but it was the best that I found. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If condition2 uses an expensive value, and yet condition2 is false, I assume that it is of the form

```
(and (expensive-calculation) (other-extra-condition))
```

What I do in these cases is:

```
(let (expensive-value)
  (cond (condition1 consequent1)
        (and (setq expensive-value (expensive-calculation)) (other-extra-condition)) consequent2)
        ((and expensive-value (other-extra-condition2)) consequent3)
```